# shell script to split file and concatenate specific parts into a new file

Tags: bash, shell

```
Category        Depth   Size    Words

entity#n#1      0       3037   acetum:dwelling:class_taxopsida:genus_salamandra:vascular_ray
abstraction#n#6 1       2373   expletive:family_hypericaceae:sound_law:scansion
```

I have a tsv file that contains many lines as the ones above. I would like to use a shell script to create a .csv file which looks like this:

```
Category   Word
entity#n#1 acetum
entity#n#1 dwelling
entity#n#1 class_taxopsida
...
abstraction#n#6 expletive
abstraction#n#6 family_hypericaceae
...
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk's split function:

```
awk '{split($4, a, ":"); for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) print $1, a[i]}' OFS="\t" file
Category        Words
entity#n#1      acetum
entity#n#1      dwelling
entity#n#1      class_taxopsida
entity#n#1      genus_salamandra
entity#n#1      vascular_ray
abstraction#n#6 expletive
abstraction#n#6 family_hypericaceae
abstraction#n#6 sound_law
abstraction#n#6 scansion
```

Comment: I get "illegal reference to array a"

Comment: Strange, can you try: `awk '{split($4, a, ":"); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]}' file`?

Comment: Yes, that worked. It seemed the OFS="\t" was causing the error. Could you explain what this does?

Comment: `OFS="\t"` was actually for adding tab character as output field separator in the awk's output. I believe `awk '{split($4, a, ":"); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]}' OFS="\t" file` should also work.